# Receiving an 'Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.' error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to run an app that I am coding along with in Android Studio 4.1 Development Essentials, Chapter 76. It is an application that uses the Android Room Persistence Library.

The error that I am getting is:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

While being fairly new to Kotlin and Android Studio, I believe the error has something to do with how my build.gradle app file is set up, show below.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "us.jordanakellogg.roomdemo"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
 
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

I will provide my DAO class as well as I feel maybe there might be something wrong with that as well.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query


@Dao
interface ProductDAO {

    @Insert
    fun insertProduct(product: Product)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName=:name")
    fun findProduct(name: String): List<Product>

    @Query("DELETE FROM products WHERE productName=:name")
    fun deleteProduct(name: String)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM products")
    fun getAllProducts(): LiveData<List<Product>>
}
```

Could you help point me in the right direction so I successfully test this app without receiving the "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'." error?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: In my case, I was adding a NON-NULLABLE variable for the table column. I made it NULLABLE variable and the error was gone. Still I think, this might be the problem of the outdated dependencies too.